# I have been retriving this error multiple times jasonpath name doesnt match

Tags: rest-assured

[image]

Below is the error that is generating. I am trying to extract name and value from the JSON body!
I am expecting in console name and value

Comment: Please, patse code and error as text, not image

Answer (score 0):

Your path to extract value is wrong. The correct path would be `.body("data.name", equalTo("jeetu"));`